# Erase function by ID for supperimposed buffer areas

Tags: postgresql, qgis

I have 200 points (=indigenous communities), I plotted 3 buffer areas (=area of ecosystem service demand) centered in each plot. What I really need is 2nd and 3rd buffer starting not from the center of the circumference, but from where it ends the previous buffer, *like a ring instead of a circumference*:

BUFFER 1 = 0 to 8 km

BUFFER 2 = 8 to 14 km (not 0-14)

BUFFER 3 = 14 to 18 km (not 0-18)

The buffers are supperimposed, so when I use the "erase" function I don`t get a good result: Rrings are cut between them, as is shown in the figure... 
[This is the bad result!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtD61.png)

I tried to do this in QGIS, and in POSTGRESQL, with the  following code, unsuccessfully:

```
CREATE TABLE maria.buffer_km14_erase AS
SELECT gid, buff_dist, id_comu, ST_DIFFERENCE (the_geom,  
    (SELECT ST_UNION (the_geom) FROM maria.buffer_km08)) AS the_geom
FROM maria.buffer_km14;
```

I think I need to add a clause that "individualize" each erase function by ID, but I don`t know how to do it! Any suggestion?

Thanks a lot!!!!

Comment: Please elaborate more on "I think I need to add a clause that "individualize" each erase function by ID, but I don`t know how to do it! Any suggestion?". If you can, provide a simplified example of the answer you are looking for.

Comment: When I say "individualize", I mean each buffer should be "erased" by the smaller buffer with the same ID, i.e. one opperation by ID (instead of dissolving all the 8km_buffer to do the opperation, as now). 
I`ve been thinking about making a loop selecting a different ID each time. The result should be a multipolygon with the complete rings. The bad thing is I`m not used with loops in Postgresql!

Answer (score 1):

@Alex

I made it using a Loop... Here is the code:

First, I created an empty table:

```
CREATE TABLE maria.buffer_km14_erase (id_comu int, the_geom geometry(Polygon,96842))  -- col names & type
```

Second, I applied the loop!

```
DO
$do$
BEGIN 
FOR i IN 1..202 LOOP  -- 202 is the maximum n
   INSERT INTO maria.buffer_km14_erase (id_comu, the_geom) -- empty table and col names
   (SELECT id_comu, ST_DIFFERENCE (the_geom,  
    (SELECT the_geom FROM maria.buffer_km08 WHERE id_comu=i)) AS the_geom
    FROM maria.buffer_km14 
    WHERE id_comu=i);
END LOOP;
END;
$do$;
```

[This is the correct result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyWvg.png)

Thanks!!!